# java execute external program and read its output

Tags: java

I want to read output from ADB logcat (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb). I have such code (test):

```
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c adb logcat");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while(true) {
            String s = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if(s == null) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("From process: " + s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this prints nothing. If I execute this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c ls");
```

It works.

Comment: Create second thread which will be printing results of process error stream. Maybe it contains some info which explains why it doesn't act the way you expect.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb logcat": error=2, No such file or directory.

I understand. LS is internal linux command, adb is installed program. I do not know how to run this external program.

Comment: This looks like crucial information which should be part of the question. Use [edit] option to place it there.

Comment: You can add your working solution below as an answer

Comment: Plenty of resources available for anyone who cares to look. like: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I too fast asked the question on SO.

I read error stream instead of inputstream and I find out that cannot find program ADB. Need to provide full path:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/home/UserName/Soft/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb", "logcat");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

But on another computer path is different. Also you can on every computer make symbolic link and in code use as path simply "adb":

```
sudo ln -s /home/UserName/Soft/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /bin/adb

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "logcat");
```

This is not the best solution, partially resolves problem. Would be great without making symbolic link, using simply "adb" in instantiating ProcessBuilder object. Because in every disk location on my computer I can use ADB in terminal, it is visible but in this code no. In Windows I know that this is in System Environments > PATH. In linux I wrote command "printenv" but I don't see anything with android & adb.